# How do I create an ArrayList that gets a list of rows in room and java (as an Async task probably)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-room

Pretty much the title really, currently what I tried is this:

`ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(userDatabase.getUserDao().getSavedUsersLists());`

but it only works if I allow main thread queries, which is obviously not ideal.

How do I do something similar but not in the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes any `non-live-data` Room queries require you to handle the background thread on your own
`AsyncTask` is deprecated now .. One of the options is [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Here is a sample:

Getting the user list query from the database

```
void getUsers(UserListListener listener) {

    Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listener.onUserListReturned(userDatabase.getUserDao().getSavedUsersLists());
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the listener interface for the returned list

```
interface UserListListener {
    void onUserListReturned(ArrayList<User> users );
}
```

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late reply; after your answer (which cleared up a few things) I discovered this article -> https://techenum.com/async-task-in-android-is-deprecated/ and used the handler approach, which works perfectly fine it seems! Just wanted to make sure if that's an ok approach or if I should avoid that? Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can use it .. the article also refers to `executors` and other options ... maybe one has advantage over the other, but the choice is your own..